# Swift OpenGL unresolved identifier kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es

I am getting a unresolved identifier error for 'kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast'. Swift can't find it. Is this available in Swift?

```
var gc = CGBitmapContextCreate(&pixelData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: width*4, imageCS, bitmapInfo: kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The last parameter of `CGBitmapContextCreate()` is defined as a struct

```
struct CGBitmapInfo : RawOptionSetType {
    init(_ rawValue: UInt32)
    init(rawValue: UInt32)

    static var AlphaInfoMask: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    static var FloatComponents: CGBitmapInfo { get }
    // ...
}
```

where the possible "alpha info" bits are defined separately as an enumeration:

```
enum CGImageAlphaInfo : UInt32 {
    case None /* For example, RGB. */
    case PremultipliedLast /* For example, premultiplied RGBA */
    case PremultipliedFirst /* For example, premultiplied ARGB */
    // ...
}
```

Therefore you have have to convert the enum to its underlying `UInt32` value
and then create a `CGBitmapInfo` from it:

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
let gc = CGBitmapContextCreate(..., bitmapInfo)
```

**Update for Swift 2:** The `CGBitmapInfo` definition changed to

```
public struct CGBitmapInfo : OptionSetType
```

and it can be initialized with

```
let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue)
```

Comment: Thanks you just saved me loads of time!

Comment: @Martin R Great Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Apple documentation suggests `CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CGImageAlphaInfo